# Cordova 3.0, Application Error The Connection to the server was unsuccessful. (Timeout)

Tags: cordova

I've am getting this timeout from trying to load my local index.html file and I cannot figure out how to increase the timeout time from the default 20 seconds. I have seen posts where people use the following lines in their droidgap extension, onCreate method:

super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

But even doing so, the app still times out after just 20 seconds. It takes longer than 20 seconds for that index.html file to load because it is using a window.open (inAppBrowser) call to fetch a remote resource.

Is there a new place where the timeout is set in cordova 3.0? I'm migrating from phonegap 2.3, where this issue didn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_dies_on_startup_connection_to_the_server_was_unsuccessful).

For me it was a case where we had to do a lot of ajax stuff when the app started up. Often (very regularly, but not *every time*) this would then seem to interfere with the low level "app is launched and running" signal to Android (Cordova?). And then the app get's killed with the above error after about 20 seconds.
So launching with an almost empty index.html and then getting that to re-direct to the real page - that seems to fool all the parties involved into believing the app is fully up and running in no-time flat.

Comment: Just a follow up on this: since about Cordova 3.5, it is possible to adjust that timeout via the config.xml file. see [the api docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was a missing js file on the local container side which was not accessed until the remote app was loaded (a cache busting scheme). Adding the file stopped the error.

I had to go deep into console.log() debugging to find this answer.