# Cordova multiple Html files

Tags: cordova

In my Cordova app the `index.html` redirects to `main.html` when I get the `onDeviceReady` event. But I can't use any plug-ins in the `main.html`.
Do I need to enable something in Cordova for `main.html` to work?

Comment: Multiple HTML files makes developing more complex, it's better to use just one HTML file. Otherwise you have to make sure, that all needed js-files, also for all plugins, are loaded. This you have to do by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you load a new page, you start over again in the App process. This means, if you load a new page, you must again wait for the `deviceready` event.

In short, everything you did in `index.html`, must be repeated in `main.html`. This is the reason people are say you should go with an SPA (Single Page App).

However, the reasons they are giving you are poor. In short, they are lazy thinkers - not lazy programmers. Multiple page apps are valid, however you must think it through. If you have questions on this, please ask.

On `deviceready` please read section **#4 In the code, did not listen for the 'deviceread' event.**
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using multiple html files, keep the Cordova application "on the same page" by having other content in other HTML files or template fragment files, and loading these in via Ajax / Javascript to a div in your index.html that is the "cur.  You might want to consider a templating engine such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), depending on which JavaScript framework(s) you are using to build your app other options may be more attractive.  Example project on Github that I have that uses this approach [can be found here](https://github.com/simonprickett/bartcordova).

Answer (score 1):

There's something you should be aware of when reading the suggestions given to make a single-page app: you may still run into the need to load another page.

This is because of a cordova timeout error I myself ran into recently where you get a timeout error message and the app crashes. The commonly known fix for this is to make the launch page for the app different from the actual app page. So, for example, you might have your entire app running on app.html, but first you need to have cordova start with loading.html and then redirect to app.html.

To answer your question, you need to move or add your onDeviceReady event to the other html file. Having a single-page app would definitely help bypass that problem (if that's the kind of app that works for you), but either way there's a chance you'll need to add that extra page to fix the timeout issue, depending on what your app logic does. It might not happen to you but I thought you should be aware of it. (The loading.html page does not need to have any onDeviceReady events, by the way; it literally can be just a single line script in the body that redirects to your app page).

Comment: do you have any information about this timeout error? It's the first time I heard about it

Comment: It's not necessarily a documented issue as far as I know, but here's another thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819824/cordova-3-0-application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-t

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone who is still facing this issue.
Add this plugin to your app, https://github.com/TruckMovers/cordova-plugin-remote-injection

This would inject cordova and other plugins into any remote HTML

Also you could place onDeviceReady in a separate JS file and include it with,

in config.xml